# Not able to send webcam video to template(.html) file using StreamingHttpResponse in Django 2.2

Tags: python, django, http, django-templates, video-streaming

I recently started django and I wanted to see the video from the laptop camera to Django 2.2 based web app. I was successful in viewing the cam video by directly sending response to web using function display_livefeed. Following is my code of views.py of app 'camerafeed'

```
class mycamera(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.frames = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    def __del__(self):
        self.frames.release()

    def get_jpg_frame(self):
        is_captured, frame = self.frames.read()
        retval, jframe = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        return jframe.tobytes()

def livefeed():
    camera_object = mycamera()
    while True:
        jframe_bytes = camera_object.get_jpg_frame()
         yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + jframe_bytes + b'\r\n\r\n')


@condition(etag_func=None)
def display_livefeed(self):
     return  StreamingHttpResponse(
            livefeed(),
            content_type='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame'
        )
```

I used **path('monitor/', display_livefeed, name='monitor'),** to see the video streaming on http://127.0.0.1:8000/monitor/ and it works perfectly [>>Image from the streaming video<<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYco5.png)

Now I wanted to display on the html template just line it is done here:
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/09/02/opencv-stream-video-to-web-browser-html-page/
but this was done by using Flask. But I wanted to do the same using Django and got stuck. Here is the html file from the above link.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Pi Video Surveillance</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Pi Video Surveillance</h1>
      <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
   </body>
```

I tried to do like this using by making this function:

```
def video_feed(request):
    return  StreamingHttpResponse(
            livefeed(), # Calling livefeed() function
            content_type='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame'
    )
```

But it able to see the video on html page using **path('', homePageView.as_view(), name='home'),** and placing code below in views.py

```
class homePageView(TemplateView):
      template_name = 'home.html'
```

I seen and tried following:

1. [Django StreamingHttpResponse into a Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116881/django-streaminghttpresponse-into-a-template)
2. [Opencv Live Stream from camera in Django Webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49680152/opencv-live-stream-from-camera-in-django-webpage)

But may be due to the fact that i am new to all these thing including web development, I might not able to get it done. Kindly help explaining me how to do this.

I am using python 3.7 and django 2.2

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, disable the monitor path from the urlpatterns. I think that the trouble is that two sources are trying to use the camera. Just comment the

`path('monitor', views.display_livefeed, name="monitor")`

and it works.